CumulusCI: Error while creating 2GP Beta Package (fr: Not available for deploy for this organization)
I am trying to build a managed package using CumulusCI. I am getting below error:
Error: fr: Not available for deploy for this organization
Any pointers how can I debug this issue? I do have a fr.translation files under translations folder.
sfdx-project.json
{
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
          "path": "force-app",
          "default": true
      }
  ],
  "name": "xxFiles",
  "namespace": "xxyy",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "60.0"
}

project-scratch-def.json
{
    "orgName": "xxFiles",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
        "languageSettings": {
            "enableTranslationWorkbench": true,
            "enableEndUserLanguages": true
        }
    }
}

Logs:
[05/15/24 22:10:43] Increased polling interval to 6 seconds                                                                                                                                             
                    [VerifyingMetadata]                                                                                                                                                                 
[05/15/24 22:10:49] [Error]: Package creation failed with error:                                                                                                                                        
                    fr: Not available for deploy for this organization                                                                                                                                  
                    Exception in task create_package_version                                                                                                                                            

[05/15/24 22:10:50] Deleting scratch org with command: sfdx force:org:delete -p -u test-@example.com                                                                                        
[05/15/24 22:10:51] Successfully marked scratch org test-@example.com for deletion                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    Warning: The force:org:delete command is deprecated. Try "org delete scratch" or "org delete sandbox" instead.                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    Warning: The "-u" flag has been deprecated. Use "--target-org | -o" instead.                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Error: fr: Not available for deploy for this organization

